# run php-script with cron does not work

Tags: php, cron, phpmailer

I hava a php-email (phpmailer 5.2.14) script which work fine when I run it in bash:

```
pi@schnickschnack: php /var/www/html/email.php
```

when i run this script with cron (sudo crontab -e):

```
*/1 * * * * root php /var/www/html/email.php
```

syslog says...

```
Jan 22 08:53:01 Schnickschnack CRON[4482]: (root) CMD (root php /var/www/html/email.php)
```

...but I get no mail. 
I have another php-script which works fine with crontab. this script inserts values from phpmodbus into a mysql-db...
does anyone have a hint why the mail-script does not work with cron?

Answer (score 2):

try

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/email.php
```

otherwise, cron tries to execute the command "root", which is not a command.

Comment: i changed this to your suggestion but the mail-script does not work

Comment: try using the full path to your php-file (on most systems, you can find it with by executing "which php" in a shell)

Comment: Do what Franz says (it's usually `/usr/bin/php`), or set a `PATH` env var in your `/etc/crontab`.

Answer (score 0):

As you are running by cron, all your usual $PATH and ENV are not available.
So CRON has no idea where to find "php".

Depending on your install - determine location of the PHP bin:

```
which php
```

use the resulting path in your cronjob. eg:

```
*/1 * * * * /bin/php /var/www/html/email.php
```

** Unless intended, dont leave the email.php script where it could be run "unintentionally" by anyone simple hitting the webserver. email.php is certainly on script kiddies hit list.